# How to connect dotnet to couchbase from another server?

Tags: .net, .net-core, couchbase

I have a couchbase windows that's installed on server development, the problem is when i tried to connecting it to dotnet it doesn't connect at all
here is my installed server development
[image]
It is just stay loading like this
[image]
here is code that using it

```
public class CouchbaseService : ICouchbaseService
{
    public ICluster Cluster { get; private set; }
    public IBucket TodoAppBucket { get; private set; }
    public ICouchbaseCollection TodoCollection { get; private set; }

    public CouchbaseService()
    {
        // TODO: get these variables via DI, possibly overriding config in appsettings.json
        var CB_HOST = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CB_HOST").DefaultIfEmpty("172.16.x.xxx:8091");
        var CB_USER = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CB_USER").DefaultIfEmpty("Administrator");
        var CB_PSWD = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CB_PSWD").DefaultIfEmpty("Batara12345");

        Console.WriteLine(
            $"Connecting to couchbase://{CB_HOST} with {CB_USER} / {CB_PSWD}");

        try
        {
            var task = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                var cluster = await Couchbase.Cluster.ConnectAsync(
                    $"couchbase://{CB_HOST}",
                    CB_USER,
                    CB_PSWD);

                Cluster = cluster;
                var bucket = await cluster.BucketAsync("TodoAppBucket");
                var collection = await bucket.DefaultCollectionAsync();
                TodoCollection = collection;
            });
            task.Wait();
        }
        catch (AggregateException ae)
        {
            ae.Handle((x) => throw x);
        }
    }
}
```

How do i should connect it?

Comment: Are you sure that the server running couchbase has the correct ports open? Try running sdk-doctor from the same machine your dotnet program is running, it can help you diagnose network issues - https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/sdk/sdk-doctor.html

Comment: thank you, but i've already installed the binary and it is give me to run using cmd, but when i tried to command cbc doctor, nothings happen

Comment: you mean SDK-doctor, not cbc doctor, right (I don't think cbc doctor exists). And when you say "nothing happen", there is no output at all? Not even error messages?

Comment: yes not showing anything, is it just show this {"meta":{"emit_interval_s":600},"operations":{}}